# Pivoting multiple columns without aggregation - Performance optimization

Tags: sql-server

I have a question regarding the performance of the following query and if it is possible to pivot multiple related columns more efficiently.

```
SELECT
  TimetableID,
  [Order],
  [Time],
  [Text],
  [1] AS FileID1, Files1.[Filename] AS [File filename1], Files1.[Extension] AS [File extension1], Files1.[Type] AS [File type1], Files1.[Content] AS [File content1],
  [2] AS FileID2, Files2.[Filename] AS [File filename2], Files2.[Extension] AS [File extension2], Files2.[Type] AS [File type2], Files2.[Content] AS [File content2],
  [3] AS FileID3, Files3.[Filename] AS [File filename3], Files3.[Extension] AS [File extension3], Files3.[Type] AS [File type3], Files3.[Content] AS [File content3],
  [4] AS FileID4, Files4.[Filename] AS [File filename4], Files4.[Extension] AS [File extension4], Files4.[Type] AS [File type4], Files4.[Content] AS [File content4],
  [5] AS FileID5, Files5.[Filename] AS [File filename5], Files5.[Extension] AS [File extension5], Files5.[Type] AS [File type5], Files5.[Content] AS [File content5],
  [6] AS FileID6, Files6.[Filename] AS [File filename6], Files6.[Extension] AS [File extension6], Files6.[Type] AS [File type6], Files6.[Content] AS [File content6],
  [7] AS FileID7, Files7.[Filename] AS [File filename7], Files7.[Extension] AS [File extension7], Files7.[Type] AS [File type7], Files7.[Content] AS [File content7],
  [8] AS FileID8, Files8.[Filename] AS [File filename8], Files8.[Extension] AS [File extension8], Files8.[Type] AS [File type8], Files8.[Content] AS [File content8],
  [9] AS FileID9, Files9.[Filename] AS [File filename9], Files9.[Extension] AS [File extension9], Files9.[Type] AS [File type9], Files9.[Content] AS [File content9],
  [10] AS FileID10, Files10.[Filename] AS [File filename10], Files10.[Extension] AS [File extension10], Files10.[Type] AS [File type10], Files10.[Content] AS [File content10],
  [11] AS FileID11, Files11.[Filename] AS [File filename11], Files11.[Extension] AS [File extension11], Files11.[Type] AS [File type11], Files11.[Content] AS [File content11],
  [12] AS FileID12, Files12.[Filename] AS [File filename12], Files12.[Extension] AS [File extension12], Files12.[Type] AS [File type12], Files12.[Content] AS [File content12],
  [13] AS FileID13, Files13.[Filename] AS [File filename13], Files13.[Extension] AS [File extension13], Files13.[Type] AS [File type13], Files13.[Content] AS [File content13],
  [14] AS FileID14, Files14.[Filename] AS [File filename14], Files14.[Extension] AS [File extension14], Files14.[Type] AS [File type14], Files14.[Content] AS [File content14],
  [15] AS FileID15, Files15.[Filename] AS [File filename15], Files15.[Extension] AS [File extension15], Files15.[Type] AS [File type15], Files15.[Content] AS [File content15],
  [16] AS FileID16, Files16.[Filename] AS [File filename16], Files16.[Extension] AS [File extension16], Files16.[Type] AS [File type16], Files16.[Content] AS [File content16],
  [17] AS FileID17, Files17.[Filename] AS [File filename17], Files17.[Extension] AS [File extension17], Files17.[Type] AS [File type17], Files17.[Content] AS [File content17],
  [18] AS FileID18, Files18.[Filename] AS [File filename18], Files18.[Extension] AS [File extension18], Files18.[Type] AS [File type18], Files18.[Content] AS [File content18],
  [19] AS FileID19, Files19.[Filename] AS [File filename19], Files19.[Extension] AS [File extension19], Files19.[Type] AS [File type19], Files19.[Content] AS [File content19],
  [20] AS FileID20, Files20.[Filename] AS [File filename20], Files20.[Extension] AS [File extension20], Files20.[Type] AS [File type20], Files20.[Content] AS [File content20]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    t.[TimetableID],
    t.[Order],
    t.[Time],
    t.[Text],
    tf.N,
    tf.FileID
  FROM
    dbo.Timetables AS t
  LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Timetable_Files AS tf
  ON
    tf.TimetableID = t.TimetableID
) AS [source]
PIVOT
(
  MAX(FileID) FOR N IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20])
) AS [fid]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files1 ON Files1.FileID = fid.[1]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files2 ON Files2.FileID = fid.[2]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files3 ON Files3.FileID = fid.[3]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files4 ON Files4.FileID = fid.[4]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files5 ON Files5.FileID = fid.[5]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files6 ON Files6.FileID = fid.[6]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files7 ON Files7.FileID = fid.[7]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files8 ON Files8.FileID = fid.[8]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files9 ON Files9.FileID = fid.[9]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files10 ON Files10.FileID = fid.[10]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files11 ON Files11.FileID = fid.[11]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files12 ON Files12.FileID = fid.[12]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files13 ON Files13.FileID = fid.[13]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files14 ON Files14.FileID = fid.[14]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files15 ON Files15.FileID = fid.[15]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files16 ON Files16.FileID = fid.[16]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files17 ON Files17.FileID = fid.[17]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files18 ON Files18.FileID = fid.[18]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files19 ON Files19.FileID = fid.[19]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Files AS Files20 ON Files20.FileID = fid.[20]
```

I have the following table structure:

Database diagram
  [image]

Every entry in T_Timetable can have multiple files attached to it. This is realized by the T_Timetable_File table.

FileIDs assigned to TimetableIDs
  [image: FileIDs assigned to TimetableIDs]

I created a view that assigns an incrementing row number to each entry in the assignment table. There is a maximum of 20 files for each entry in the timetable.

```
CREATE VIEW
  dbo.Timetable_Files
AS
  SELECT
    TimetableID,
    FileID,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY TimetableID ORDER BY FileID ASC) AS N
  FROM
    dbo.T_Timetable_File
```

I need to output the result in the following format, which the query at top of the question already does.

Result
  [image]

The concern with this query is the amount of memory SQL Server assigns to it. While the query could possibly return a massive amount of data when all timetable entries contain the maximum of 20 files, most of the time an entry has none to a maximum of 5 files attached to it. As such it also throws an "excessive memory grant" warning.

I am also not very satisfied with my solution of joining the Files view (the view is just a select of all columns of the table used for later rights management) 20 times to get all file information for the 20 possible attached files.

```
CREATE VIEW
  dbo.Files
AS
  SELECT
    ID AS FileID,
    [Filename],
    Extension,
    [Type],
    Content
  FROM
    dbo.T_File
```

My question: Is there a better / faster, more elegant way to pivot the 5 columns of each file entry?

Edit: In the meantime I found something here:

[Using pivot and unpivot to pivot multiple columns](https://dzone.com/articles/pivoting-and-unpivoting-multiple-columns-in-ms-sql)

Using this information I rewrote the query to look like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    t.[TimetableID],
    t.[Order],
    t.[Time],
    t.[Text],
    N,
    CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), f.FileID) AS FileID, /* f.Content is varbinary, so to unpivot the other columns they have to converted to varbinary, too */
    CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), f.[Filename]) AS [Filename],
    CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), f.Extension) AS Extension,
    CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), f.[Type]) AS [Type],
    f.Content
  FROM
    dbo.Timetables AS t
  LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Timetable_Files AS tf
  ON
    tf.TimetableID = t.TimetableID
  LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Files AS f
  ON
    f.FileID = tf.FileID
)
SELECT
  TimetableID,
  [Order],
  [Time],
  [Text],
  CONVERT(int, FileID1) AS FileID1, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename1) AS Filename1, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension1) AS Extension1, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type1) AS Type1, Content1, /*Convert the other columns back to their original type*/
  CONVERT(int, FileID2) AS FileID2, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename2) AS Filename2, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension2) AS Extension2, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type2) AS Type2, Content2,
  CONVERT(int, FileID3) AS FileID3, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename3) AS Filename3, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension3) AS Extension3, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type3) AS Type3, Content3,
  CONVERT(int, FileID4) AS FileID4, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename4) AS Filename4, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension4) AS Extension4, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type4) AS Type4, Content4,
  CONVERT(int, FileID5) AS FileID5, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename5) AS Filename5, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension5) AS Extension5, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type5) AS Type5, Content5,
  CONVERT(int, FileID6) AS FileID6, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename6) AS Filename6, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension6) AS Extension6, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type6) AS Type6, Content6,
  CONVERT(int, FileID7) AS FileID7, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename7) AS Filename7, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension7) AS Extension7, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type7) AS Type7, Content7,
  CONVERT(int, FileID8) AS FileID8, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename8) AS Filename8, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension8) AS Extension8, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type8) AS Type8, Content8,
  CONVERT(int, FileID9) AS FileID9, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename9) AS Filename9, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension9) AS Extension9, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type9) AS Type9, Content9,
  CONVERT(int, FileID10) AS FileID10, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename10) AS Filename10, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension10) AS Extension10, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type10) AS Type10, Content10,
  CONVERT(int, FileID11) AS FileID11, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename11) AS Filename11, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension11) AS Extension11, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type11) AS Type11, Content11,
  CONVERT(int, FileID12) AS FileID12, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename12) AS Filename12, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension12) AS Extension12, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type12) AS Type12, Content12,
  CONVERT(int, FileID13) AS FileID13, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename13) AS Filename13, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension13) AS Extension13, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type13) AS Type13, Content13,
  CONVERT(int, FileID14) AS FileID14, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename14) AS Filename14, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension14) AS Extension14, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type14) AS Type14, Content14,
  CONVERT(int, FileID15) AS FileID15, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename15) AS Filename15, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension15) AS Extension15, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type15) AS Type15, Content15,
  CONVERT(int, FileID16) AS FileID16, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename16) AS Filename16, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension16) AS Extension16, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type16) AS Type16, Content16,
  CONVERT(int, FileID17) AS FileID17, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename17) AS Filename17, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension17) AS Extension17, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type17) AS Type17, Content17,
  CONVERT(int, FileID18) AS FileID18, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename18) AS Filename18, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension18) AS Extension18, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type18) AS Type18, Content18,
  CONVERT(int, FileID19) AS FileID19, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename19) AS Filename19, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension19) AS Extension19, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type19) AS Type19, Content19,
  CONVERT(int, FileID20) AS FileID20, CONVERT(varchar(400), Filename20) AS Filename20, CONVERT(varchar(400), Extension20) AS Extension20, CONVERT(varchar(400), Type20) AS Type20, Content20
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TimetableID,
    [Order],
    [Time],
    [Text],
    Variable + CONVERT(varchar(2), ISNULL(N, '0')) AS [Variable], /* Without the ISNULL timetable entries without files will not be displayed */
    [Value]
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      TimetableID,
      [Order],
      [Time],
      [Text],
      N,
      ISNULL(FileID, 0x0) AS FileID,
      [Filename],
      Extension,
      [Type],
      [Content]
    FROM
      CTE
    GROUP BY
      TimetableID,
      [Order],
      [Time],
      [Text],
      N,
      FileID,
      [Filename],
      Extension,
      [Type],
      [Content]
  ) AS origresult
  UNPIVOT
  (
    [Value] FOR Variable IN (FileID, [Filename], Extension, [Type], [Content])
  ) AS unpiv
) AS intermediateresult
PIVOT
(
  MAX([Value]) FOR Variable IN
  (
    FileID1, Filename1, Extension1, Type1, Content1,
    FileID2, Filename2, Extension2, Type2, Content2,
    FileID3, Filename3, Extension3, Type3, Content3,
    FileID4, Filename4, Extension4, Type4, Content4,
    FileID5, Filename5, Extension5, Type5, Content5,
    FileID6, Filename6, Extension6, Type6, Content6,
    FileID7, Filename7, Extension7, Type7, Content7,
    FileID8, Filename8, Extension8, Type8, Content8,
    FileID9, Filename9, Extension9, Type9, Content9,
    FileID10, Filename10, Extension10, Type10, Content10,
    FileID11, Filename11, Extension11, Type11, Content11,
    FileID12, Filename12, Extension12, Type12, Content12,
    FileID13, Filename13, Extension13, Type13, Content13,
    FileID14, Filename14, Extension14, Type14, Content14,
    FileID15, Filename15, Extension15, Type15, Content15,
    FileID16, Filename16, Extension16, Type16, Content16,
    FileID17, Filename17, Extension17, Type17, Content17,
    FileID18, Filename18, Extension18, Type18, Content18,
    FileID19, Filename19, Extension19, Type19, Content19,
    FileID20, Filename20, Extension20, Type20, Content20
  )
) AS piv
```

Using unpivot first did the trick for me. The query does not generate memory warnings and performs much faster as it only accesses the File table once (according to SQL Server statistics).

I will also try the approach suggested by larnu and compare the speed of the execution. Thanks so far.

Comment: Do it in your presentation layer instead? That query is most definitely going to perform awfully. You're actually calling the tables `Timetables` and `Timetable_Files` 20 times each. Generally I find the presentation layer is far better at pivoting your data than SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I already thought about that. Given the fact that most entries have not many files attached I also thought about splitting the query into multiple queries. Fetching only the FileIDs in unpivoted form and then querying the details for each file afterwards. But this would result in more queries against the database. Something I wanted to avoid. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why would it result in more queries? The query would be far simpler (just your initial `SELECT` in your subquery), and then the presentation does all the work.

Comment: Looks like you are doing things in the wrong order. Instead of pivoting first then joining onto the 20 pivoted columns do the join first then you can use `MAX(CASE WHEN ...)` to do the pivoting of multiple columns

Comment: I will try out the suggestions. In the meantime I found another solution (shown in the edited question). Thanks so far.